# bootstrap's drop down list for segmented button not working in firefox 27.0.1

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a simple search field using bootstrap's segemented button (see example at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-segmented).

My code looks like the following and is available at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jwayne2978/E2ACU/.

```
<div style="width:500px; margin:auto">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Search</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">option 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that this html code works for chrome v33.0.x.y and ie v10, but not firefox v27.0.1.

In firefox, instead of the drop-down list appearing right underneath the drop-down button to the right, it is appearing underneath the search field to the left.

Any idea on what's going on? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `pull-right` class for the dropdown.  It should be:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2ACU/2/)**

When that class is added, Bootstrap will apply the following styles:

```
.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

Note - I added a `btn-sm` class to your dropdown-toggle too to line it up.